# how to get value from associative array

Tags: php, associative-array

This is my array :

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => S No.
            [1] => Contact Message
            [2] => Name
            [3] => Contact Number
            [4] => Email ID
        )

        [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => I am interested in your property. Please get in touch with me.
            [2] =>  lopa  <br/>(Individual)
            [3] => 1234567890
            [4] => <a href="mailto:loperea.ray@Gmail.com">loperea.ray@Gmail.com</a>
        )

        [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => This user is looking for 3 BHK Multistorey Apartment for Sale in Sohna, Gurgaon and has viewed your contact details.
            [2] =>  shiva  <br/>(Individual)
            [3] => 2135467890
            [4] => <a href="mailto:sauron82@yahoo.co.in">sauron82@yahoo.co.in</a>
        )
)
```

How can I retrieve all data element wise?

Comment: What do you mean by "element wise"?

Comment: It's whole data, you got it already. What do you need exactly?

Comment: Now I want value of Contact Message,Name,Contact Number, Email ID.

Comment: what would be the final output look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can get information about arrays in PHP on [the official PHP doc page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

You can access arrays using square braces surrounding the key you like to select `[key]`.

So `$array[1]` will give yoo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => I am interested in your property. Please get in touch with me.
    [2] =>  lopa  <br/>(Individual)
    [3] => 1234567890
    [4] => <a href="mailto:loperea.ray@Gmail.com">loperea.ray@Gmail.com</a>
)
```

And `$array[1][2]` will give you:

```
lopa  <br/>(Individual)
```

Or you can walkt through the elements of an array using loops like the [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) or the [`for`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) loop.

```
// perfect for assoc arrays
foreach($array as $key => $element) {
    var_dump($key, $element);
}

// alternative for arrays with seamless numeric keys
$elementsCount = count($array);

for($i = 0; $i < $elementsCount; ++$i) {
    var_dump($array[$i]);
}
```

Comment: I am using same method but not getting result.  `code`foreach($data as $da){ echo $da[0][1]; } `/code`

Comment: Have you turned on `display_errors` in your testing env and set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL`? If you select an element of an array in a foreach loop you have to have 3 levels in an array. In your array in the question I just see two levels. So you probably try to select an entry from a string. This will fail. But activate errors and PHP will tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have integer indexed elements in multidimensional array. To access single element from array, use array name and it's index `$myArray[1]`. To get inner element of that previous selected array, use second set of `[index]` - `$myArray[1][5]` and so on.

To dynamically get all elements from array, use nested `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($myArray as $key => $values) {
   foreach ($values as $innerKey => $value) {
       echo $value;
       // OR
       echo $myArray[$key][$innerKey];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$header = array_map(
  function() { return []; }, 
  array_flip( array_shift( $array ) ) 
); // headers

array_reduce( $array , function ($carry, $item) {
  $i = 0;
  foreach( $carry as $k => $v ) {
    $carry[$k][] = $item[$i++];
  }
  return $carry;
}, $header );
```

First of all we get the header from the very first element of input array. Then we map-reduce the input.

That gives:

```
$array = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c3']];
/*
  array(3) {
    'A' =>
    array(3) {
        [0] =>
        string(2) "a1"
        [1] =>
        string(2) "a2"
        [2] =>
        string(2) "a3"
      }
    'B' =>
    array(3) {
        [0] =>
        string(2) "b1"
        [1] =>
        string(2) "b2"
        [2] =>
        string(2) "b3"
      }
    'C' =>
    array(3) {
        [0] =>
        string(2) "c1"
        [1] =>
        string(2) "c2"
        [2] =>
        string(2) "c3"
      }
  }
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
$array = Array
(
        0=> Array
        (
                0 => 'S No.',
                1 => 'Contact Message',
                2 => 'Name',
                3 => 'Contact Number',
                4 => 'Email ID'
        ),

        1 => Array
        (
                0 => 1,
                1 => 'I am interested in your property. Please get in touch with me.',
                2 =>  'lopa  <br/>(Individual)',
                3 => '1234567890',
                4 => '<a href="mailto:loperea.ray@Gmail.com">loperea.ray@Gmail.com</a>',
        ),

        2 => Array
        (
                0 => 2,
                1 => 'This user is looking for 3 BHK Multistorey Apartment for Sale in Sohna, Gurgaon and has viewed your contact details.',
                2 =>  'shiva  <br/>(Individual)',
                3 => '2135467890',
                4 => '<a href="mailto:sauron82@yahoo.co.in">sauron82@yahoo.co.in</a>',
        )
);

$result_array = array();
array_shift($array);
reset($array);

foreach($array as $x=>$array2){
    foreach($array2 as $i => $arr){     
        if($i == 1){
            $result_array[$x]['Contact Message'] = $arr;
        }elseif($i == 2){           
            $result_array[$x]['Name'] = $arr;
        }elseif($i == 3){           
            $result_array[$x]['Contact Number']  =$arr;
        }elseif($i == 4){           
            $result_array[$x]['Email ID'] = $arr;
        }
    }   
}

print_r($result_array);
```